# Are there any known numerical ways (and if possible libraries in C) to solve this kind of differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, integro-differential-equations

I have been trying to mimic a paper's solution of some, probably not so hard, equations.

They say they solve them with 4th order Runge Kutta.

To my knowledge, I don't think this is possible, but here I show an example:

$$y'(t) = y(t) +  \int_0^t \dfrac{1}{1+y(t)y(x)}dx$$

or generally a function $f(y(t),y(x))$ inside the integral.

I don't really understand how I could solve this numerically (Also, I can't bring the form of it to be an ODE.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code, calculates the ODE:

$$y'(t) = -\int^t_0 y(x) dx +1$$
with $y(0)=0$

which is equivelant to
$$y''(t) = -y(t)$$ with $y'(0) =1$ and $y(0)=0$

and starts out correctly, but as time goes on, integration error adds up (probably due to method)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h>

struct solve_params { std::vector<double> y0;
                      std::vector<double> dt;};


double integ_in(double t, const double y[],
      void *pp){

     struct solve_params * params = (struct solve_params *)pp;
     std::vector<double> y0       =  (params->y0);
     std::vector<double> dt        =  (params->dt);


  unsigned int vecSize = dt.size();
  //printf ("%.5e \n",y0[vecSize-1] );
  double result = 1;


  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vecSize; i++)
  {
    // access value in the memory to which the pointer
    // is referencing
    result += -dt[i]*y0[i];
  }

  return result;
}




int
func (double t, const double y[], double f[],
      void *pp)
{
  f[0] = integ_in(t, y,pp);
  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}


template <typename TT, typename f_point> 
void RK (TT param_tt,  f_point myf, double init[], double t, double t1)
{
  gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {func, NULL, 1, &param_tt};

  const gsl_odeiv2_step_type * T
    = gsl_odeiv2_step_rkf45;
  int i;
  
    gsl_odeiv2_step * s
    = gsl_odeiv2_step_alloc (T, 1);
  gsl_odeiv2_control * c
    = gsl_odeiv2_control_y_new (1e-6, 0.0);
  gsl_odeiv2_evolve * e
    = gsl_odeiv2_evolve_alloc (1);
  double h = 1e-6;
  double y[1] = {init[0]};
  double told = t;
  while (t < t1)
    {
      int status = gsl_odeiv2_evolve_apply (e, c, s,
                                           &sys,
                                           &t, t1,
                                           &h, y);

      if (status != GSL_SUCCESS)
          break;

      printf ("%.5e %.5e %.5e %.5e\n",t ,h ,y[0], sin(t) );
      param_tt.dt.push_back(t-told);
      param_tt.y0.push_back(y[0]);
      told = t;
    }


  gsl_odeiv2_evolve_free (e);
  gsl_odeiv2_control_free (c);
  gsl_odeiv2_step_free (s);
  return ;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  double t = 0.0;
  double t1 = 100;
  double y[1] = { 0.0 };
  double told = t;
  std::vector<double> y0;
  std::vector<double> tt;
  tt.push_back(told);
  y0.push_back(y[0]);
  solve_params temp;
  temp.y0=y0; 
  temp.dt=tt;
  RK(temp,func,y,t,t1);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Runge-Kutta is a little complicated so I'm going to illustrate the idea that the article you mention is probably using by some simple methods.

Let our integral-differential equation be
$$y'(x)=F(x, y(x))+G(x, y(x))\int_0^xdt\,H(x, y(x), t, y(t))$$
and $h>0$ be some step size. Given $y(0)$ we can then approximate our solution by $y(x)\approx y_{\lfloor x / h\rfloor}$ for some sequence $\{y_n\}$. To that end, we approximate the derivative by a difference

$$y'(x)\approx \frac{y_{\lfloor x / h\rfloor+1}-y_{\lfloor x / h\rfloor}}{h}$$

and the integral by a numerical quadrature (in this case a simple rectangle rule)

$$\int_0^xdt\,f(y(t))\approx h\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x / h\rfloor}f(y_k)$$

so our differential equation becomes a one step recurrence relation for $y_n$ when we look at $x=nh$:

$$y_{n+1}\approx y_n+hF(nh, y_n)+h^2G(nh,y_n)\sum_{k=0}^nH(nh,y_n,kh,y_k),\quad y_0 = y(0).$$

These ideas generalize quite well to different derivative approximations (e.g. Runge-Kutta) and quadrature rules (e.g. trapezoids).

EDIT: To give an illustration, here's an example C implementation of this simple method:

```
void solve(
  double (*F)(double, double), double (*G)(double, double),
  double (*H)(double, double, double, double),
  double y0, double x, double h, double *y)
{
  int n = (int)(x / h);
  y[0] = y0;
  for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    y[i + 1] = y[i] + h * F(i * h, y[i]);
    for(int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
       y[i + 1] += h * h * G(i * h, y[i]) * H(i * h, y[i], j * h, y[j]);
    } 
  }
}
```

This will evolve the differential equation up to `x`, where you pass in a pointer `y` that has at least `(x / h) * sizeof(double)` bytes. The solution to your differential equation can then be read off in `y`. If instead of the whole function you just want its value at `x` (not sure why you'd want that), you can modify this implementation to return a `double` corresponding to $y(x)$ and do allocation/freeing of `y` at runtime instead of having it as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So you need to keep "information" of the solution you already build right? Also, you have forgotten a term $h$ to multiply the sum right?     Lastly, do you know such routines in any programming language to be present (excluding mathematica)? Or I have to build them alone

Comment: @BillyMatlock Yes, I forgot the step sizes in the recurrence, thanks for pointing it out. I don't believe anything like this comes prepackaged with any general purpose programming languages, so I added a sample C implementation. You can maybe find libraries that do this in python or something, but if you know how to write an RK4 solver and simple quadrature estimators, you can probably pull this off in an afternoon.

Comment: I Implented in  GSL's routine, which is weird to me how it's not included, that's why I would question if something like this is accurate, but I trust you since I dont have any other way :D

Comment: @BillyMatlock Since this involves integration, errors are near impossible to control using fixed step sizes. You can work around this by using adaptive meshes to bound your errors, but then if you want to stick to C you're probably going to be using and abusing recursion and compiler extensions for simulated closures to keep your code readable. That may or may not be what you want, and it will likely significantly increase the space complexity of the method. You have to think about these details, but if a simple integrator is not cutting it, maybe it's a good idea to go further like that.

Comment: I posted a new answer, which is working with  GSL, hope you find it nice? :D